# Use null as default for a field in Avro4k

Tags: kotlin, avro

I am using avro4k and I have a field that is nullable, like this:

```
@Serializable
data class Product(
    @AvroDefault("null")
    @ScalePrecision(DEFAULT_SCALE, DEFAULT_PRECISION)
    @Serializable(with = BigDecimalSerializer::class)
    val price: BigDecimal? = null
)
```

This is the generated schema:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Product",
  "namespace" : "org.company",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "ask",
    "type" : [ {
      "type" : "bytes",
      "logicalType" : "decimal",
      "precision" : 7,
      "scale" : 2
    }, "null" ],
    "default" : "null"
  } ]
}
```

Avro specification [expects](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2509) that null should not have the quotes.

I think it's also a problem that the null types appears last in the schema, according to the documentation:

> Unions, as mentioned above, are represented using JSON arrays. For example, ["null", "string"] declares a schema which may be either a null or string.
> (Note that when a default value is specified for a record field whose type is a union, the type of the default value must match the first element of the union. Thus, for unions containing “null”, the “null” is usually listed first, since the default value of such unions is typically null.)

Is there a way to fix both these issues?

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to use Avro.NULL in that case.

```
@Serializable
data class Product(
    @AvroDefault(Avro.NULL)
    @ScalePrecision(DEFAULT_SCALE, DEFAULT_PRECISION)
    @Serializable(with = BigDecimalSerializer::class)
    val price: BigDecimal? = null
)
```

It also fixes the order.

Comment: An addition to this is that one should import the correct library for ```@AvroDefault``` see: https://github.com/avro-kotlin/avro4k/issues/97